# Undo translation made with Jquery Translate (Google Translate API v2)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, google-translate

I've been using [this jQuery plugin](https://github.com/michaeldewildt/jquery-translate/) to help me interact with Google Translate API v2 and it's all been working very nicely so far.

However I want to give the user an option to **undo the translation** but I can't see any obvious way to return the language back to its source (and I don't want to 're-translate' the string back into the original language).

Comment: Remember the original yourself and seplace with it the translation?

Comment: Looks like you need to implement your own logic to untranslate elements. You could use data() to save original string before any translating then reload it if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing your translated content before you translate it may be the best solution. Since your using jquery anyway, take a look at .html() --> http://api.jquery.com/html/

Translation example:

```
var content = $('.element').html();
$('.element').translate();
```

I suppose this is possible, but you will need to test this:

```
var content = $('.element').html();
var translated_content = $(content).translate();
$('.element').html(translated_content);
```

Now to return to original:

```
$('.element').html(content);
```

So wrap some functions and some event listeners around this and jobs done!

---

**Edit: alternative approach**

After rethinking my original approach above, think it's easier to just hide the original and add a translated copy.

**Note:** Using .clone() has the side-effect of producing elements with duplicate id attributes, which are supposed to be unique. Where possible, it is recommended to avoid cloning elements with this attribute or using class attributes as identifiers instead.

Functions:

```
function translate(object){
   var clone = $(object).clone().addClass("trans_translation"); //copies the object
   $(object).addClass("trans_original"); //adds a identifier to the original
   $(object).after(clone); //inserts the clone to the html
   $(object).next(".trans_translation").translate(); //translate the new div
   $(object).hide(); //hides to original
   $(object).next(".trans_translation").show(); //shows the translation
}

function toggle_translation(bool){
  bool = bool || false; //default parameter
  if(bool){ //if true, show translation, hide original
    $(".trans_translation").show();
    $(".trans_original").hide();
  } else { //if false (default), hide translation, show original
    $(".trans_translation").hide();
    $(".trans_original").show();
  }
}
```

Document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".trans_translation").css( "display", "none" ); //hides the translations on default

  //example button to translate a div
  $(".translateme").click(function() {
    var object = $(this).parent(); //selects the parent of the button
    translate(object);
  });

  //example button to hide translated and show original on page
  $(".givemetheoriginal").click(function() {
    toggle_translation();
  });

});
```

HTML BODY:

```
<div class=".content">
  <p>This is just a text</p>
  <div class=".translateme">translate this div</div>
</div>
<div class=".content">
  <p>This is just a text</p>
  <div class=".translateme">translate this div</div>
</div>
<div class=".content">
  <p>This is just a text</p>
  <div class=".translateme">translate this div</div>
</div>
<div class=".givemetheoriginal">Show the original!</div>
```

Have not tested this, but suppose should work.

Note: Oops, you should first rename the translate function because the translate plugin has the same name.

Comment: You know when you've been looking at something for too long and then feel like an idiot for not thinking of the logical approach.. that's how I feel right now. Thanks! I've moved onto another project but will look over this tomorrow. Much appreciate the speedy answer!

Comment: Looks like the jquery plugin doesn't like to run on a variable. I've ended up doing this (so far) which feels very long winded (but I'm not a js coder) - http://pastebin.com/UawSvx2J

Comment: sessionStorage.setItem has come in handy :)

Comment: After rethinking my suggested approach i think it might be a good idea to just hide your original stuff instead of replacing it. will edit my answer and add example.

Comment: That looks like a good approach - I'll test it out later this afternoon. Thanks!

Comment: Hey there, my apologies for not coming back on this but I got wholly distracted with some server side troubles! http://pastebin.com/CP7QTUQJ is what I went with in the end. I was having so much trouble with offering multiple translation options that I dropped it and just went with a translate to X, undo translation option. Thanks so much for your help pointing me in the right direction.